# Apostrophe cms: An error occurred saving the document

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

In my Apostrophe app I have a page type called backend:

```
{% extends 'apostrophe-templates:layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ super() }} | Home{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Backend</h1>
    {{
      apos.singleton(data.page, 'Registered users', 'registered-users')
    }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I think it's a pretty straightforward one. in app.js I have `'registered-users-widgets': {}` declared in modules, and of course, I have a module; `registered-users-widgets` folder with `index.js` and `views/widget.html`.

In index.js there is:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    name: 'registered-users',
    label: 'Registered users',
    contextualOnly: true
```

And widget.html:

```
<div>TEST</div>
```

I added new backend page, accessed it, added Registered users. It nicely displayed TEST in the right place, but soon after I got a notification `An error occurred saving the document.` POST to save-area returned with code 200 and response `{"status":"error"}`.
There's no error getting thrown in the server console, I removed the page and reregistered, once by the built-in remove, second - directly on the database, but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your area name field (second argument) must be an intercap string like registeredUsers. Spaces are not permitted.